# Can I specify the default option for an "asp-items" list directly in the .cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have an ASP.Net Core form like this:

```
<div class="form-group" id="DW_Q30_div">
    <label>@Questions.Q30*</label>
    <select asp-for="Answers.Q30" asp-items="DropdownValues.DeployEnvironments"></select>
</div>
```

This is the corresponding Dropdown list:

```
public class DropdownValues
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> DeployEnvironments { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "OnPremises", Text = "On Premises" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Cloud", Text = "Cloud" }
    };
    ...
```

Q: Is there any way I can specify the default item (for example, "Cloud" instead of "OnPremises") directly in the .cshtml markup itself?

Comment: Yes, set "selected" = to true in the SelectListItem properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LarryBud already commented change you code to this if you want select "Cloud" instead of "OnPremises:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> DeployEnvironments { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "OnPremises", Text = "On Premises" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "Cloud", Text = "Cloud" , Selected=true }
    };
```

for your edit you can use this code:

```
var defaultValue=...your value from db.
foreach(var item in DeployEnviroments)
{
if item.Value==defaultValue item.Selected=true;
}
```

Comment: I confirmed: 1) If I set `new SelectListItem { Value = "Cloud", Text = "Cloud" , Selected=true }`, then 2) the "Create" page correctly defaults to "Cloud", 3) If I create a new item and set "DeployEnvironments" to "OnPremises" (non-default), then 4) the "Edit" Page shows "On Premises" (*NOT* "Cloud").  Which is exactly what I wanted :)  No need to modify any controller .cs, no need for any ViewBags, I don't even need the "foreach()" loop.  It just works :)  Thank you (and  LarryBud) again!